# What does 'in kind' mean in "The kind of reasoning just described is similar in kind to that invoked..."?

Tags: meaning

> The kind of reasoning just described is similar **in kind** to that [the kind of reasoning] invoked in discussing conversational implicatures, reflecting the fact
> that both phenomena are pragmatic.

What does 'in kind' mean?

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-kind) defines: If you do something in kind, you do the same thing to someone that they have just done to you.

And the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/kind_1#kind_idmg_1) defines: with the same thing.

Neither of them would fit well here.